# command to open dialoge box

Tags: script, vbscript, dialog

Running Windows 10 Pro here. I am using a simple script that acts as a shortcut to my Windows game controller configuration, but I always have to manually navigate to the 'properties' button in the dialog box to get to where I really want to get to. This first image is where the shortcut takes me to:

[image]

Now the place I want to go is the next page that can be achieved by pressing the'Properties' button:

[image]

I would like to alter the script so that it automatically goes to this second page of the game controller config dialog. Is there a way to modify the script, or even write a new one that will accomplish this? Here is the .vbs script (generated by a program called Tileconfiy that allows pinning shortcuts to the start menu):

```
Dim targetPath, targetArguments

targetPath = """C:\Windows\explorer.exe"""
targetArguments = "C:\Windows\System32\joy.cpl"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\"
WshShell.Run targetPath & " " & targetArguments, 1
WshShell.AppActivate("joy.cpl")
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

The Game configuration opens fine but the TAB, and ENTER part are not executing. I have tried several variations on this last part of the code including the following:

```
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

and

```
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("{~}")
```

and

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB})";
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("~");
```

and

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}";
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("ENTER");
```

None of which seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'--- AUTOGENERATED BY TILEICONIFIER - DO NOT MANUALLY EDIT ---
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Custom Shortcut Type = "Explorer"
'Shortcut Name = "JOYSTICK WIn10"
'Shortcut Path = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TileIconify\Custom Shortcuts\JOYSTICK WIn10_1\JOYSTICK WIn10.lnk"

Dim targetPath, targetArguments

targetPath = """C:\Windows\explorer.exe"""
targetArguments = "C:\Windows\System32\joy.cpl"

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Windows\"
WshShell.Run targetPath & " " & targetArguments, 1
WshShell.AppActivate("Game controllers")
Wscript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

First it opens the Game controllers dialog. Then activates the window and makes click on the Properties button.

Comment: I wish this worked, but it doesnt..Its close, but `TAB` is not working, (and so I guess neither is `ENTER`). I have updated my original question with a modified version of your answer, but it still is not tabbing to the next part.

Comment: Please check the edited code

Comment: the `WshShell.Sleep 2000` causes error:  "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: Sorry mistakenly done the typo, fixed it. It is a method of Wscript object

Comment: this works well. I will treasure all that I have learned here. Thank you.